# Logminer archived redo logs in other database

Tags: oracle-10g

Can I move my archived redo logs to other database and apply logminer there to analyze them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm) it clearly states:

> There are four basic objects in a LogMiner configuration that you
>   should be familiar with: the source database, the mining database, the
>   LogMiner dictionary, and the redo log files containing the data of
>   interest:
>
> - The **source database** is the database that produces all the redo log
>     files that you want LogMiner to analyze.
> - The **mining database** is the database that LogMiner uses when it
>     performs the analysis.